# Python etree control empty tag format

Tags: python, xml

When creating an XML file with Python's etree, if we write to the file an empty tag using `SubElement`, I get:

```
<MyTag />
```

Unfortunately, our XML parser library used in Fortran doesn't handle this even though it's a correct tag. It needs to see:

```
<MyTag></MyTag>
```

Is there a way to change the formatting rules or something in etree to make this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Python 3.4, you can use the `short_empty_elements` argument for both the [`tostring()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) and the [`ElementTRee.write()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write):

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.tostring(ET.fromstring('<mytag/>'), short_empty_elements=False)
b'<mytag></mytag>'
```

In older Python versions, (2.7 through to 3.3), as a work-around you can use the `html` method to write out the document:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.tostring(ET.fromstring('<mytag/>'), method='html')
'<mytag></mytag>'
```

Both the `ElementTree.write()` method and the `tostring()` function support the `method` keyword argument.

On even earlier versions of Python (2.6 and before) you can install the external ElementTree library; version 1.3 supports that keyword.

Yes, it sounds a little weird, but the `html` output mostly outputs empty elements as a start and end tag. Some elements still end up as empty tag elements; specifically `<link/>`, `<input/>`, `<br/>` and such. Still, it's that or upgrade your Fortran XML parser to actually parse standards-compliant XML!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no other Fortran XML parser to use, so this is our only option. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance there is a way to maintain the case of the tag? Apparently case sensitivity is an issue also and `html` doesn't preserve case...

Comment: Can't have it all... Thanks for answering the question though!

Comment: If I want to read an XML and write to another XML after adding End tags, how can I do that?

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R: that's not really a clear question. Do you mean writing to another XML *file*? Then just use the `write` method with the `method` argument set: `ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring('<mytag/>')).write(fileobj, method='html')`.

Comment: It means in the same file. Suppose I have a tag like `<SampleTag Attrib1="apple" />`
Now I have to generate another file using same tags but the output file should contain like this: `<SampleTag Attrib1="apple"><SampleTag/>`.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R: that's not valid XML, but if you wanted `<SampleTag Attrib1="apple"></SampleTag>` then that's exactly what this answer does; and if you want to write directly to a file, use the `.write()` call I gave you in my comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think I couldn't explain you well. Please see this XML: [Input](https://www.filedropper.com/input_5) and I need to modify in such a way that I get the [output](http://www.filedropper.com/output_5) . I agree that we can use `.write` but that is when creating a new xml. I want to read the input xml tree and output to the output xml file. I think both input and output XMLs are valid here.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R: so what's the problem exactly? Use the ElementTree API to add the text to each node and write out again.

Answer (score 5):

This was directly solved in Python 3.4. From then, the `write` method of `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` has the `short_empty_elements` parameter which:

> controls the formatting of elements that contain no content. If True (the default), they are emitted as a single self-closed tag, otherwise they are emitted as a pair of start/end tags.

More details in the [xml.etree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

Answer (score 3):

Adding an empty `text` is another option:

```
etree.SubElement(parent, 'child_tag_name').text=''
```

But note that this will change not only the representation but also the structure of the document: i.e. `child_el.text` will be `''` instead of `None`.

Oh, and like Martijn said, try to use better libraries.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 2.7. It will ignore it, except if you actually write something, like a whitespace for example, `' '`.

Comment: this also doesn't work in Python 3.8, still the empty elements gets short.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sed available, you could pipe the output of your python script to

```
sed -e "s/<\([^>]*\) \/>/<\1><\/\1>/g"
```

Which will find any occurence of `<Tag />` and replace it by `<Tag></Tag>`

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the code, the version of `ElementTree.py` I use contains the following in a `_write` method:

```
write('<' + tagname)
...
if node.text or len(node): # this line is literal
    write('>')
    ...
    write('</%s>' % tagname)
else:
    write(' />')
```

To steer the program counter I created the following:

```
class AlwaysTrueString(str):
    def __nonzero__(self): return True
true_empty_string = AlwaysTrueString()
```

Then I set `node.text = true_empty_string` on those ElementTree nodes where I want an open-close tag rather than a self-closing one.

By "steering the program counter" I mean constructing a set of inputs—in this case an object with a somewhat curious truth test—to a library method such that the invocation of the library method traverses its control flow graph the way I want it to. This is ridiculously brittle: in a new version of the library, my hack might break—and you should probably treat "might" as "almost guaranteed". In general, don't break abstraction barriers. It just worked for me here.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 2.7 at least. I added the class below my imports, and then did assign the `true_empty_string` to the node's `text`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python >=3.4, use the `short_empty_elements=False`option as has been shown in other answers already, but:

1. If you have the XML in string form already and can't touch the code
   where it's generated..
2. If you're in a situation where you are stuck with python <3.4..
3. If you're using a different XML library that insists on self-closing tags..

Then this works:

```
 xml = "<foo/><bar/>"
 xml = re.sub(r'<([^\/]+)\/\>', r'<\1></\1>', xml)

 print(xml)

 # output will be
 # <foo></foo><bar></bar>
```