# python after writing a xml tree back to file cause a different style on closing tags - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I am modifying XML documents xml.etree.ElementTree and afterwards I write the new (modified) XML Structure to a new file.

If I compare the original one with the new one, I see that python change the style of the closing tags.

Original style:

```
<prop name="Type"></prop>
```

Modified Style:

```
<prop name="Type" />
```

I know that new style is totally correct, but I am worried a bit, that it might cause some bad side affects on the legacy system I am working on. So is there a chance to have the same closing style as in the original XML document ( `<prop name="Type"></prop>` and not the short one `<prop name="Type" />`)

The modified tree is written back to file via:

```
tree.write(panelModPath,encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python etree control empty tag format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460677/python-etree-control-empty-tag-format)

Answer (score 2):

[write](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method accepts `method` argument. You can set it to `html` to preserve closing tag.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import BytesIO

source = """
<prop name="Type"></prop>
"""

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(source))
file = BytesIO()

tree.write(file, encoding='utf-8', method="html", xml_declaration=True)

print(file.getvalue())
```

Prints:

```py
b'<prop name="Type"></prop>'
```