# create a xml with just root tag using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to create a xml file with just one root tag without any subElements to it.

I tried with following code

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

I am getting filename.xml as below:

<root />

But I am expecting as below:

<root>

</root>

without any internal tags in root

Comment: What you got is fine. Its the same as you are expecting.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12460677/407651.

Comment: Also note that `xml.etree.cElementTree` is deprecated since Python 3.3 (just use `xml.etree.ElementTree`).

Answer (score 0):

The element can be self-closing if it is empty, meaning your output is valid XML.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp